# Enunciating utility maximization problem using set theory

Tags: notation, game-theory, fuzzy-set

I need to enunciate a problem using set theory and I am not sure how to start. The problem goes like this:

You are a car manufacturer and need to decide how many colours to use in your next bash of cars. Assuming that you can only produce one car model but you are able to decide among an infinite range of colour, and the more colours you use the more expensive the batch. On the other side, you have a finite group of people. All of them will buy a car and have different colour preferences (for example, they like red 1, brown 0.5, and blue 0.02 etc). The situation is basically the more colours you use, the more satisfaction among customers but the lower your profits. I know fuzzy sets are part of the equation, but I am not sure how to put everything together formally. Also game theory might be useful?

Any help/ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is more important: price or color satisfaction? How are they weighted?

Comment: I was assuming that the weight between variables was not important, meaning that the optimum at the end would depends on variables outside the problem. Kind of a parametric relationship. Not sure if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be the [infinite] set of all colors, and $P$ be the [finite] set of all people. For all $p \in P$, $f_p: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a color-liking function where a higher value means a greater satisfaction with that color.

Assumptions:

- The total color satisfaction for a person is the sum of the satisfactions for each color and the total color satisfaction for $P$ is the sum of the total color satisfactions of all people in $P$.
- The price of coloring the car is dependent only on the number of colors; i.e. the price function is $q: \mathbb{Z}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.
- The price and the total color satisfaction are geometrically weighted (as opposed to arithmetically, or exponentially, or harmonically, etc.) and that the weights are $w_p$ and $w_c$, respectively.

Then, the task is to choose some colors $D$ for your car, $D \subset C$, such that
$$\sqrt[w_p + w_c]{t_p^{w_p}t_c^{w_c}}$$
is minimized, where
$$
t_p = \sum_{c \in D} q(c) \\
t_c = \sum_{p \in P} \sum_{c \in D} f_p(c)
$$
($t_p$ is the total cost and $t_c$ is the total color satisfaction.)

Comment: thank you for your answer, that is really amazing. A couple of questions and I am done. What do $C$, $t_p$, and $t_c$ represent?

Comment: @vabm $C$ is given in the first line of my answer, and $t_p$ and $t_c$ are the total price and total cost respectively.

Comment: thank  you, and apologies, I actually meant $D$

Comment: @vabm Edited to explain that.

Comment: if $w_c$ weights color satisfaction, why $t_c$ is total cost instead of total color satisfaction? And why $p∈P$ if $p$ is a price function? Thanks

Comment: @vabm Sorry, I chose a bad notation. Edited.